# How to filter the first element of the nested list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to filter nested lists by their first element.

```
[[7000, '2009-09-23'],
 [200000, '2019-09-23'],
 [100, '2004-01-30']]
```

I need to have as the output the nested list with a condition that the first element is lower than 10000.

```
[[7000, '2009-09-23'],
 [100, '2004-01-30']]
```

I have tried to write this code:

```
filtered = [x[0][0] for x[0][0] in newList if x[0][0]<10000]
```

But I don't understand the concept of looping through the indexing of the nested list.

Answer (score 2):

If your list is called `outer` then you can look at each element `inner` (which is in itself a list) and decide, based on the first value of `inner`, if you want to add it to the filtered list. This would look something like this:

```py
filtered = [inner for inner in outer if inner[0] < 10000]
```

This is roughly equivalent to the following code:

```py
filtered = []
for inner in outer:
    if inner[0] < 10000:
        filtered.append(inner)
```